# Is there a way to create a Trigger on a View that fires whenever there has been a change in its underlying tables in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, triggers

I have 2 tables (`MY_TABLE1`, `MY_TABLE2`) that I need to JOIN in order to store their result in another table (`MY_TABLE3`) and I need every state of that JOIN statement accross time. (Basically `MY_TABLE3` will be used as an event buffer table where these changes will be stored for a while and then get flushed)

Is there any way to create a VIEW for this JOIN statement and then create a TRIGGER for that View that fires whenever an update or insert has been performed in its underlying tables (`MY_TABLE1`, `MY_TABLE2`)?

As far as I've read the docs, Views can only have `INSTEAD OF` triggers which are being used to replicate the DML to it's underlying tables. Is that wrong?

PS. Any other suggestion that possibly solves my problem is also welcome :)

Comment: A `VIEW` is just a `SELECT` statement and the output will automatically reflect changes to the underlying tables so it is unclear why you think you need a trigger to update the view.

Comment: You may also want to look at Advanced Queuing (AQ).

Comment: Can you use a materialized view, with a trigger on that (or rather its underlying table) that can populate `table3`? You might want to step back and look at when/how the current tables are updated, and see if you can directly capture relevant changes; depends on the data though (e.g. if you're aggregating).

Comment: @MT0 I'm sorry for the confusion. I don't need a trigger to update the view, **I need a trigger that fires when the view is updated (so that I can insert into `MY_TABLE3`)**. Also thanks for the suggestion on AQs but I think my version of Oracle doesn't support this :'(

Comment: @AlexPoole How is the first thing you suggested different to what I said? I'm sorry I'm fairly new to this :'). Also, the project I'm working on is maintained for years and the DB is not normalized properly, the 2 tables that I want to join should be 1 :') and this is what causes me the trouble of trying to insert into one table while having a 2-table-trigger basically, I'm not trying to aggregate data or do anything complex, I just want the exact data of the columns. These tables are currently filled in by different sources though so I cannot take that "step back" as you said.

Comment: @HerculesKonsoulas - you're talking about a normal view, I'm talking about a materialized view. You can't have a trigger when a normal view changes, as MTO said, as it's just a stored query; but [a materialized view](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/dwhsg/basic-materialized-views.html#GUID-A7AE8E5D-68A5-4519-81EB-252EAAF0ADFF) is a different thing, the results of the view query are stored (materialized), and you *can* have a trigger on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is not the solution that I was asking but since I found no other way, I'll post how I solved my issue.

Inside `MY_TABLE3` I added 2 more `INVISIBLE` columns, the ID on which the tables are being `JOIN`ed and the `TRANSACTION_ID` of the last time this row was modified or created.

This way I could now create 2 Triggers that fire on insert, update and delete, and insert a new row in `MY_TABLE3` or merge in an already existing one, depending on whether I find the current transaction_id in a row of the table, the details that I need from each of the other tables.

> **NOTE:** The only edge case that I find possibly bug-prone that I haven't tested yet or hasn't emerged yet is that, during the fire time of the trigger (since there is no table-locking for triggers), someone might flush the buffer table. In that case, you may need to fine-tune the way your trigger works if you're following my way.